# Create a file in python

Tags: python, hashtable

Now i know how to implement a dictionary by file txt.
So i have create the example.txt (generic file) :

```
aaa.12
bbb.14
ccc.10
```

and to make a dictionary:

```
with open('example.text') as f:
    hash = {}
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split('.', 1)
        hash[key] = int(value)
```

So now i want to order my elemen by value: so i try

```
with open('example.txt') as f:
    hash = {}
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split('.', 1)
        hash[key] = int(value)
        print hash #this print my dict
        value_sort=sorted(hash.values())
        print value:sort #to check the what return and gave me in this case value_sort=[10, 12, 14]
```

perfect so now how can i write on example.txt my items order by value:

```
ccc.10
aaa.12
bbb.14
```

Comment: Just curious, Why a downvote on this question?

Comment: Maybe the downvoter thought that you should use a proper serializer instead of inventing your own. You could use pickle or json.

Comment: Maybe - due to the poor grammar - the downvoter couldn't understand what was being asked.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop through the `hash` dict separately, where you ask it to be sorted on value:

```
from operator import itemgetter

hash = {}
with open('example.text') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split('.', 1)
        hash[key] = int(value)

for key, value in sorted(hash.items(), key=itemgetter(1)):
    print '{0}.{1}'.format(key, value)
```

The `sorted()` call is given a key to sort by, namely the second element of each `.items()` tuple (a key and value pair).

If you wanted to *write* the sorted items to a file, you'd need to open that file in writing mode:

```
with open('example.txt', 'w') as f:
    for key, value in sorted(hash.items(), key=itemgetter(1)):
        f.write('{0}.{1}\n'.format(key, value))
```

Note that we write newlines (`\n`) after every entry; `print` includes a newline for us but when writing to a file you need to include it manually.

Comment: Martijn, I think the OP wants to write the sorted items to a file, not print them -- could be wrong, though.

Comment: @martineau: I think you could be right, the last sentence seems to indicate that.